# Different sort order for has_many :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have the following models set up -

```
Product has_many Categories through Categorisations
Category has_many Products through Categorisations
```

I'm wondering what the correct way would be to put the products in different orders in each category. For example, a product might be first in one category and last in another. The ordering will be based purely on which item is most appropriate in each category, rather than alphabetical etc.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Categorisation model add a column 'sort_order'.

Also add following in the Categorisations model.

```
default_scope order("sort_order ASC")
```